# If/else statement in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to Visualforce/Apex and I am trying to construct an if else statement to render two different views dependent on alias (one view for a certain alias and another view for everyone else). I am trying to do something like:

```
<apex:page >

if {
<apex:include pageName="Lead_Log_Report" rendered="{!$User.Alias == 'asheldon'}"/>

}

else {
<apex:include pageName="Sales_rep_leads" 

}
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Visualforce has its own expression language and constructs that are separate from Apex. I'll edit your question as you probably can't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[refer this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003854&type=1)

```
<apex:page >
     <apex:include pageName="Lead_Log_Report" rendered="{!IF($User.Alias ='asheldon',true,false)}"/>
     <apex:include pageName="Lead_Log_Report" rendered="{!IF($User.Alias ='mfountai',true,false)}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: `IF($User.Alias ='asheldon',true,false)` is the same as `$User.Alias='asheldon'`.

Answer (score 1):

Rendered attribute will hide the element if it gets false value and show element if true, below code should work for you.

You need to use not and or operator as below, just replace your second page with `Another_Page`

```
<apex:page >
      <apex:include pageName="Lead_Log_Report" rendered="{!($User.Alias == 'asheldon' || User.Alias == 'mfountai')}"/>
      <apex:include pageName="Another_Page" rendered="{! NOT($User.Alias == 'asheldon' || $User.Alias == 'mfountai')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I am specifically trying to do an if/else statement because I have about 40 users and I don't want to create a render action for each alias. I simply want to render a specific page for two users then another page for the rest, if that makes sense

Comment: so you want to show `Lead_Log_Report` page for users with alias `asheldon` and `mfountai` and some another for rest of all?

Comment: Yes exactly, do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @WernerAdewoleupdaetd answer please check

Comment: Hi rahul, thanks for this. I slightly edited your code as it threw a couple syntax errors, namely the apostrophes. It looks like it works (enables me to save it), however, the rule itself does not seem to be working? I tried logging in as another user to test and they got directed to the same page..

Comment: @WernerAdewole Apologies for inconvenience and thanks for bringing it into notice i have corrected the code.

Comment: Great all works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<apex:include pageName="{!IF($User.Alias ='asheldon','Lead_Log_Report','Sales_rep_leads')}" />
```